# Deserialize variable saved on GPU on GPU

Tags: pytorch

I saved the parameter variable on my computer (equipped with GPU and CUDA). The weights were saved with the GPU mode. Then when attempting to load the weights on the same computer, I still get an error:

```
RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA device but torch.cuda.is_available() is False. If you are running on a CPU-only machine, please use torch.load with map_location='cpu' to map your storages to the CPU.
```

The issue is related to the fact that `torch.cuda.is_available()` returns False.

The issue disappears after restarting the computer but then reappears after some time.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `map_location` argument to `torch.load`, i.e.,modify your code

from `torch.load(model_weights)`

to `torch.load(model_weights, map_location=torch.device('cuda:0'))`